# How to set fixed window size for Universal Windows Application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, win-universal-app

I just started to develop an Universal Windows Application in VS2015 Community Edition. I have used the sample called PieCharts for Windows UWP.

My problem is that I whould like to fix the window size to 400x650 as I did in my old desktop applications. I have set Width and Height manually It does not work. My MainPage.xaml is something like the following code.

```
<Page x:Class="MyFistUWP.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:local="using:MyFistUWP"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  MaxHeight="650" MinHeight="650" MaxWidth="400" MinWidth="400" Height="650" Width="400" >

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="Resources/my_logo.png" />
</Grid>
```

The window size is wrong and I can resize window.

Thanks,

Comment: Bear in mind that UWP applications can run on devices with differing screen orientations and sizes, and not all UWP platforms support windowing of apps (e.g. Phone)

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code for set minimal size of application:
 `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size(400, 650))`;

Comment: Yes, I have that code in MainPage constructor. It works correcty but I can still resize window more than 400x650.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't set maximum size for UWP application

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. I think its not the best, but it works.
XAML:

```
     <Grid Background="#4A9130" SizeChanged="FormName_SizeChanged">
```

c#

```
    private void FormName_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TryResizeView(new Size(900, 600));
    }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I guess the only choice is use OnSizeChanged Method to control size of window. It's work's for me. Maybe not the best choice but really easy way to solve problem.

```
private void FormName_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if((this.Width != 400) & (this.Height != 650))
    {
        this.Width = 450;
        this.Height = 650;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do this, won't you still see the maximize button and the resizing arrows?

Comment: Sure...That is one big problem. But this code reset the window back to wanted size. Have to say that to solve problem in this way is not beauty but it works ... somehow.

Comment: what about tablet mode ?