# Set Application Size in Universal Windows Application for Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8

This is for windows phone UWA, how do i set a specific window size for application? like when i open the application, i dont want a FULL SCREEN application, i want a small application that is not taking the entire phone screen, what kind of solution am i looking at?

What did i try? this:
[How to set fixed window size for Universal Windows Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065512/how-to-set-fixed-window-size-for-universal-windows-application)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e2dbd9c5-0ce2-4323-9462-347cba6e1d0b/uwp-min-and-max-size-of-window?forum=wpdevelop

i tried others too and still couldnt get it

```
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(100, 100);
        ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
```

tried this too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All apps are full-screen on Windows Phone; the preferred window size is for the Desktop OS.

Comment: What Visual Studio layout can i use to do a partial size windows phone app?

Comment: You can make your content any size you want, but the app will always fill the screen.