# How do I make uwp app size smaller it should be simple

Tags: uwp, size

I am trying to make a very simple UWP app smaller than default but i can't.
How to do this?
As you can see in the image the windows calculator app and the notepad is smaller in width than my app. I can't make it smaller???

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGTBb.png)

I have looked on google and this site but can't find any answers.
It should be simple???
If this has been answered please guide me to the answer.
Thanks

Comment: if you are mentioning about app window size, this will help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36065512/how-to-set-fixed-window-size-for-universal-windows-application

Comment: If the above comment is not helpful, please describe your problem clearly .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought it could be done in XAML part. But this work thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.preferredlaunchviewsize?view=winrt-22621) to set the size of your UWP APP.

1. Set a minimum value for the size using [ApplicationView.SetPreferredMinSize(Size) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.setpreferredminsize?view=winrt-22621#windows-ui-viewmanagement-applicationview-setpreferredminsize(windows-foundation-size)).
2. Set a value for the size of the app as you want by setting the [ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.preferredlaunchviewsize?view=winrt-22621)
3. Apply the size by setting [ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.preferredlaunchwindowingmode?view=winrt-22621#windows-ui-viewmanagement-applicationview-preferredlaunchwindowingmode).

Please refer to the following code:

```
        public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        //set minimized size
        ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size(200, 200));
        // change to smaller size
        ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(400, 400);
        ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought it could be done in XAML part. But this work thanks